# elasticsearch slow log wont write to log file

Tags: elasticsearch

Im trying to to capture the index request  by enabling  the slow log option .

I read this  [search-slow-log](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html#search-slow-log)   and tried few configuration but in both cases nothing has been written to the slow log file.

What is the correct way to configure  slow log option in order to capture the  query's that has been  sent to the ES server ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your slow log configuration?

There are two parts to enabling slow logs.

The first is to enable the slow logs by providing the various thresholds in the elaticsearch.yml config file. The default config file does not have these thresholds and the default behavior is to disable slow logs if these thresholds are not provided.

For example:
index.search.slowlog.threshold.query:
        warn: 10s
        info: 5s
        debug: 2s
        trace: 500ms

To enable logging all requests, set at least one level (the choice is dependent on your logging preference) to 0ms.

The second part is to enable the actual logging of the slow log events. The default logging.xml config file should log these events by default.